# Why the bootstrap menu disappearing after click on it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, magento

I am using Magento and jQuery for my website.  I have some issues on my bootstrap toggle menu when I click on the dropdown button, the dropdown disappears.

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2"
          data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-car"></i> Automobiles
    <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="sub-cat">
        <h3>Cars <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span></h3>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="" title="">Toyota</a></li>
          <li><a href="" title="">Suzuki</a></li>
          <li><a href="" title="">Ford</a></li>
          <li><a href="" title="">BMW</a></li>
          <li><a href="" title="">Others</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you take a screenshot and highlight the problem.

Comment: i am sorry, i couldn't post screenshot please open this link and in the left sidebar you can see the categories links when you click on any of the category it will be move. http://naijashop.com.ng/index.php

Comment: Try uploade here http://imgur.com/ and gave me the link of the screenshot thx.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/KT8dkQp.jpg?1

Comment: and then what will happen next if click that link?

Comment: yeah i alredy check it and disappear probably you in wrong collapsing

Comment: please suggest me that i can solve this issue.

Comment: Update. Check my answer. i guess it fix. if you follow my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have faced this issue several times.

This issue is caused due to a conflict between  prototype.js, jquery.js, bootstrap.js etc

Add this code:

```
(function() {
    var isBootstrapEvent = false;
    if (window.jQuery) {
        var all = jQuery('*');
        jQuery.each(['hide.bs.dropdown', 
            'hide.bs.collapse', 
            'hide.bs.modal', 
            'hide.bs.tooltip',
            'hide.bs.popover'], function(index, eventName) {
            all.on(eventName, function( event ) {
                isBootstrapEvent = true;
            });
        });
    }
    var originalHide = Element.hide;
    Element.addMethods({
        hide: function(element) {
            if(isBootstrapEvent) {
                isBootstrapEvent = false;
                return element;
            }
            return originalHide(element);
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: This has really really really helped me

Answer (score 6):

for the most modern version of jQuery maybe use the above solution not very good. So I will prefer just simple use with code like this:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your button html from:

```html
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2"
        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  <i class="fa fa-tags"></i>
  Brand Store                                        
  <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
</button>
```

Into:

```html
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
```

Let me know if this work. Thank you

Comment: Thank you ! This work for me now but is this good way to do ?

Comment: Yeah, hopefully. Try double check again. :)

Comment: after removing data-toggle="dropdown", i can't see dropdown list. Is there any other way to do this

Comment: @vashishth please make a new question. I will try help you to solve it. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by [Amit Bera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2940291/amit-bera) is mostly correct. However, it's not necessary to attach the event handlers to all elements with `jQuery('*')`. Instead, for Bootstrap components that are loaded automatically, we can attach the handlers directly to the `document`. For Bootstrap components that you have to initialize manually, it's important to use delegated events, otherwise the event handlers won't be attached to elements added to the page dynamically. Here's an updated answer:

```
const $document = jQuery(document);
let isBootstrapEvent = false;

// These events are attached directly to the document by bootstrap
const BOOTSTRAP_DOCUMENT_EVENTS = [
  'hide.bs.dropdown',
  'hide.bs.collapse',
  'hide.bs.modal',
];

BOOTSTRAP_DOCUMENT_EVENTS.forEach((eventName) => {
  $document.on(eventName, () => {
    isBootstrapEvent = true;
  });
});

// These events are bound directly to the relevant elements
const BOOTSTRAP_OPT_IN_EVENTS = {
  '[data-toggle="tooltip"]': 'hide.bs.tooltip',
  '[data-toggle="popover"]': 'hide.bs.popover',
};

Object.keys(BOOTSTRAP_OPT_IN_EVENTS).forEach((selector) => {
  const eventName = BOOTSTRAP_OPT_IN_EVENTS[selector];
  $document.on(eventName, selector, () => {
    isBootstrapEvent = true;
  });
});

const originalHide = Element.hide;
Element.addMethods({
  hide(element) {
    if (isBootstrapEvent) {
      isBootstrapEvent = false;
      return element;
    }
    return originalHide(element);
  },
});
```